# как передать значения переменной в функцию?

Tags: javascript

часть кода такая:

```
var result = 'hello world hello world';

document.getElementById('enter').innerHTML = '<button onclick="go(result)" class="btn btn-default another">Проверка</button>';
```

Как правильно передать **result** в функцию, пробовал простым методом '+result+' , но на выходе получаю очень страшный хтмл, строка гуляет по всему элементу button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `innerHTML` использовать довольно накладно. Проще и быстрее работает динамическое создание и управление объектами DOM дерева:

```js
var result = 'hello world hello world',
    go = function(str) { alert(str); };

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.className = 'btn btn-default another';
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Проверка'));
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    go(result);
}, false);

document.getElementById('enter').appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="enter"></div>
```

Comment: Хах, опередил, я пока код структурировал, ты запостил ответ, в общем-то похожий на мой. Или мой похожий на твой - это с какой стороны смотреть, хотя яйца и в профиль, и в анфас - одна хрень...

Comment: @TheDoctor Факт. Хотя твой код создает `<input>` элемент, а мой -- `<button>`. В остальном, действительно, один в один `:)`

Comment: Мне инпуты больше греют душу `:)` `innerHTML` лучше юзать в других местах, но не создании кнопки, на которую нужно навесить обработчик.

Comment: @TheDoctor Ну это до тех пор пока в евоный bootstrap не потребуется какую-нибудь `glyphicon` запихнуть: там уж либо `<button>`, либо вообще нечто вроде `<a>`.

Comment: Угу, хотя от bootstrap'а у меня глаза скоро вытекать начнут: jQuery портит JS, а BS - HTML/CSS.

Comment: @TheDoctor Ну, я бы сказал иначе: jQuery -- это такой основательный костыль, который все еще спасает многие сайты от хромоты, но становится менее и менее актуальным с каждым новым поколением препарата под названием JavaScrtipt. А Bootstrap -- это просто неплохой набор косметики, скрывающей юношеские прыщи. О как философски завернул `:)`

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22819/discussion-between-thedoctor-and-vision).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы вам обоим)

Answer (score 2):

Забудь о `onClick`, это рудимент прошлого.
Сделай так:

```js
var result = 'hello world hello world';
function go(e){
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 'Function <strong>go</strong> has been started with arguments: <em>' + e + '</em>';
}

var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = 'button';
btn.className = 'btn btn-default another';
btn.value = 'Проверка';
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){go(result);});
document.getElementById('enter').appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<div id='enter'></div><br />
<span id='result'>&nbsp;</span>
```

**UPD:**

Опередили чуть-чуть :)

Comment: `:P` . . . . . .